# extension change for .mov to .mp4

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to switch .mov files picked by a UIImagePickerController to .mp4 ones. I've gotten that it's enough to simply switch extensions, however I can't figure out how to change the name... No property on NSData, or not even a hit on google...

Could anyone please give me a hint in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to move `Foo.mov` to `Foo.mp4`?

```
NSString *path = @"/path/to/foo.mov";
NSString *newPath = [[path stringByDeletingPathExtension] stringByAppendingString:@".mp4"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:path toPath:newPath error:NULL];
```

Comment: @Tom I can only hope the file is not in the app bundle (this won't work if it is).

Comment: It would be the standard for image library and where newly captured movies through UIImagePickerController are stored.

Comment: Guess that would mean it's in the bundle then... Got Cocoa error 262 which according to some googling meant something's wrong with my url... Am I completely screwed or is there still a way?

Comment: @Tom So do you want to move files which have been captured using the camera app? You can't do that unless jailbroken, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Tom Also note that initializing URLs with file paths works using `+ [NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`. `+ URLWithString:` takes URL strings, not bare file paths.

Comment: Well, the thing is it needs to be .mp4 to cope with android devices, and our api manager told me to do it from the device... Guess I'll look more into an AVAsset export way I read something about. Was using URLWithString. I'll try to change it.

Comment: It worked!
Just gotta try it on an android device now. However your work here is done. Thanks again!